# Excel VBA autofilter alphanumeric data range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data range in column A with five digit alphanumeric, eg. 20000.00001, 30001.00001, ec001.00002, dc001.00001......., I try to do auto filter based on data range selection, eg. Data more than >25000.00001 and contained dc001.xxxxx, but it always come out blank field with auto filter activated.  I set autofilter criteria 1 with ">25000.00001" and criteria 2 with "dc*" but not successful. 
‌
Anyone know what is the correct method to do this with VBA?

Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Are the values in column **A** *Numeric* or *Text* ??

Comment: Please remember that this is not a code writing service. Give it a try and we can help with resolving any issues with your code

Comment: Perhaps you need to use an ***OR*** condition rather than an ***AND*** condition.  **Post your current code and a sample of your data.**

Comment: hi all, i have figured out it with record macro, thanks! 

Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BC$992").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=**c**" _
        , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">30000.00001"